# How to create circled background at the bottom with gradient and shadow

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Can anybody help me to achieve this header layout without using images for shadows?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: why not image? or try this border-radius: 50%;

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

Comment: use this: background-position: 50% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;

Comment: yea, I tried couple of stuffs but nothing with success

Comment: I already solve this on the site gotadaa.com. There are more things which are applied, like 92vh on the <header> and different styles on header pseudo classes :before and :after. Check the css and you will find the solution – Milan Savov 9 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not impossible to achieve with CSS. You'd just need to look at the different layers of that image and recreate each of them using `background-image`. The image has three distinct layers. The bottom most layer is an angled linear gradient which goes from a darker shade of blue to a lighter shade (from bottom left to top right). The second is a circular radial gradient which produces the glow by overlaying a gradient which goes from white to transparent on top of the bottom layer and the third one is another radial gradient (elliptical) which produces the gray shadow. By creating the layers and adding them to an element we can get the required output.

The curved bottom part of the shape can be produced by using `border-radius` with different radii in the X and Y axis.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -5%;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 150% 150% / 0% 0% 60% 60%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 160%, rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.75), rgba(127, 127, 127, 0) 40%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 40%), linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(43, 149, 241), rgb(136, 208, 249));
  background-size: 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 100%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='shape'></div>
```

Comment: Great. This help me a lot. I have only problems with the black shadow .. because there is an image at bottom-center, the shadows is below it and it isn't visible. Also, is it possible, the line above the image to be straight line so the image wouldn't go out of the line ? Here is a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/33LQaWwkZa0

Comment: I already solve this on the site http://gotadaa.com/. There are more things which are applied, like 92vh on the <header> and different styles on header pseudo classes :before and :after. Check the css and you will find the solution